# Updating a DateTime field in SQL Server db from Date and Time fields

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime

In a SQL Server 2008 database I have a table with a **Date** field of datatype `date` and a **Time** field of datatype `time`. The table contains some data.

Then I added a **DateTime** field of datatype `datetime` and wanted to populate this field with values from corresponding **Data** and **Time** fields (of the same row).

I can update either *date* or *time* part of **DateTime** field by executing:

```
SET [DateTime] = Cast([Date] as datetime)
```

or

```
SET [DateTime] = Cast([Time] as datetime)
```

But how to correctly combine these operations and update the whole **DateTime** field?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
UPDATE  mytable
SET     [DateTime] = CAST([Date] AS DATETIME) + CAST([Time] AS DATETIME)
```

Comment: Casting one side is sufficient to promote the other implicitly

Comment: Why didn't I see this answer before.. My bad :(